# How to extract coordinates from Google Maps link (PHP or Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I have a google map link that looks like this:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Space+Needle/@47.620506,-122.349277,17z/data=!4m6!1m3!3m2!1s0x5490151f4ed5b7f9:0xdb2ba8689ed0920d!2sSpace+Needle!3m1!1s0x5490151f4ed5b7f9:0xdb2ba8689ed0920d

How can I extract coordinates from it in PHP or Javascript to get an array:

```
{47.620506, -122.349277}
```

Comment: are you using the google maps api?

Comment: do you need to embed the map? if so click settings on the map and click embed map. copy and paste code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using the api (Which isn't advisable), you could just put the page into a string, and extract the long/lat from within ... It's given multiple times on the page as the parameter `ll` ... I'm not very good with regex, so I'll give an example using `strstr`

```
<?php
    $url='https://www.google.com/maps/place/Space+Needle/@47.620506,-122.349277,17z/data=!4m6!1m3!3m2!1s0x5490151f4ed5b7f9:0xdb2ba8689ed0920d!2sSpace+Needle!3m1!1s0x5490151f4ed5b7f9:0xdb2ba8689ed0920d';
    $result=file_get_contents($url);
    $ll=explode(',',substr(strstr(strstr($result,'?ll='),'&',true),4));
    $long=$ll[0];
    $lat=$ll[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I am using on my web page at the moment. It is fairly easy to do as well.

```
 <div id="map-canvas">

            <script>
            function initialize() {

                var myLatlng;
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 13,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

                        //User Location
/* This is the cords */ myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    //So if you want them individually just use position.coords.l... 
    //Please feel free to ask questions

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use php it is quite easy to query the maps api with just about any address that Google will recognize:

```
$address = 'Space+Needle';
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($response);
$ltlg = array($result->results[0]->geometry->location->lat, $result->results[0]->geometry->location->lng);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public function getCoordinatesAttribute() {
        $url = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Space+Needle/@47.620506,-122.349277,17z/data=!4m6!1m3!3m2!1s0x5490151f4ed5b7f9:0xdb2ba8689ed0920d!2sSpace+Needle!3m1!1s0x5490151f4ed5b7f9:0xdb2ba8689ed0920d";
        $url_coordinates_position = strpos($url, '@')+1;
        $coordinates = [];

        if ($url_coordinates_position != false) {
            $coordinates_string = substr($url, $url_coordinates_position);
            $coordinates_array = explode(',', $coordinates_string);

            if (count($coordinates_array) >= 2) {
                $longitude = $coordinates_array[0];
                $latitude = $coordinates_array[1];

                $coordinates = [
                    "longitude" => $longitude,
                    "latitude" => $latitude
                ];
            }

            return $coordinates;
        }

        return $coordinates;
    }
```

In my case, I have to make sure that the link is a google map location URL as it all depends on
the character "@" in the url.