# Extract Latitude and Longitude from Google Map Link

Tags: php, regex

Supposing I had the  following link to a google map:
https://www.google.com.gh/maps/place/Niagara+Falls/@43.0828162,-79.0763516,17z/data=!4m15!1m9!4m8!1m0!1m6!1m2!1s0x89d34307412d7ae9:0x29be1d1e689ce35b!2sNiagara+Falls,+NY+14303,+United+States!2m2!1d-79.0741629!2d43.0828162!3m4!1s0x89d34307412d7ae9:0x29be1d1e689ce35b!8m2!3d43.0828162!4d-79.0741629

I would like to extract only the latitude and longitude from the following link.  I assume I would need to use regular expression to do this but I have no idea how to go about it.

The co-ordinates in this case would be 43.0828162,-79.0763516

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract coordinates from Google Maps link (PHP or Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907130/how-to-extract-coordinates-from-google-maps-link-php-or-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a simple RegX like this

```
preg_match('/@(\-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+),(\-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/', $url, $match );
```

You can see it here, using your url.

https://regex101.com/r/hD7lV0/1

just for sake of explaining it

- Match `@` Literal At sign one time
- Match `-`, literal hyphen/minus `?` one or none times
- Match `[0-9]`, `+` one or more times
- Match `\.` literal `.` decimal one time
- Match `[0-9]`, `+` one or more times
- Match `,`, literal `,` comma one time
  etc...

Answer (score 1):

I would do.

```
<?php
    $latLong = split(',',preg_match('/@([0-9\.-,]*?)\//',$url));
    // $latLon = [lat, long] = $latLon[0],$latLom[1]
?>
```

- Match @ Symbol (as start of match)
- Any Number, Fullstop, minus or comma up-until the next '/' (escaped with '\')
- Split it into two parts on the ','

If needs be you can test it with

```
if (count($latLon) > 2){
    die('Invalid URL Segment found.');
}
```

*If you want to be really short with your regex*

```
    $latLong = split(',',preg_match('/@(.*?)\//',$url));
```